# how to link wordpress/buddypress to a sub domain

Tags: mysql, wordpress, dns, subdomain, buddypress

I'm trying to understand how my sub domain would still fetch data from the original website address. Im creating a mobile version of my site, for example: www.m.website.com and I'm running wordpress and buddypress. My question is, how would I grab information for my users? Do I have to install wordpress and buddypress again on the sub domain? And how would I access my database via the sub domain? Thanks ahead of time guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running two WordPress sites off the same database presents a few issues. My opinion is to use a plugin like [**WordPress Mobile Pack**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/) or [**DudaMobile**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobile-website-builder-for-wordpress-by-dudamobile/) to setup your mobile site. These plugin will detect the mobile devices and switch the style to mobile version.

Another option is to use [Responsive design](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/responsive), or scaling elements of the site based on the available space. [Reading this Article](http://www.blogtips.org/how-to-enable-mobile-theme-on-wordpress-blog/) will also help you.

Cheers !!!